# Calling JS function from Wasm module

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

I wrote a program in C for printing prime numbers up to the given number.
I want to compile this to WebAssembly and every time when isPrime() is true I'd like to call JS function "document.write(i + ">br>")" just to print out prime numbers in browser. So in fact I want to call JS function from wasm module.
 
I know this tool: https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/ for compiling from C to wasm.
Thanks for any help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int isPrime(num) {
    int i;
    if(num == 2) return 1;
    if(num % 2 == 0) return 0;
    int sq = (int) sqrt(num) + 1;
    for(i = 3; i < sq; i = i + 2) if(num % i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

void printPrimes(int n){
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        if(isPrime(i))
            /* here I want to call: JSfunction->document.write(i + "<br>");*/
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [edit] your code to include a question.  You've listed the things you want to do, what's preventing you from achieving your goals?

Comment: I guess, it's ok now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emscripten docs describe several different ways in which you can interact between JavaScript and Webassembly:

https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html.